# Creating & writing to a file (with permission 755) from PHP fails as PHP runs as 'nobody' and target file owner is another user

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions, fopen

I am writing a PHP code that creates another PHP file with fopen and writes to it. It runs on most shared environments without any problem but in some old servers and customized servers the code fails to create file and write to it even though the folder permission is 755 as the PHP runs under the account 'nobody' and the folder owner is another user.

In shared servers the folder owner and the PHP both runs under same user and so there are no permission issues.

Can anyone help me out here with a solution please.....

Thank you All...

EDIT: This problem might have bugged many others including packages like Joomla, Drupa, etc. How do they get around this problem? Can anyone explain please. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the same group as well?

Comment: The file has to run on multiple servers across the internet and I won't have any control over their setup... The solution needs to be at my end (which I think is nearly impossible) and if not it should be very easy for the end users to do... Will adding the user to group be easy for non-linux gurus?

Comment: I fail to see the reasoning. Do you have permission to write on those servers across the Internet? If you do have permission, how come they don't provide you with a reasonable way to do so? If I want my gardener to come take care of my garden, I will have to let him in, won't I?

Comment: This is a very old thread. I don't even remember which project i was working on when i posted this question. :) Of course, the problem is not as simple as the garden example. Not many people are technical enough to give proper permissions to the files or they may be on shared servers to which they do not have proper control. As I mentioned this was for old servers or customized servers. I don't think many people would face this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct solution to this problem. So the only solution was to show the user a relevant message and ask them to copy the files manually...

Answer (score 1):

If PHP runs as user 'nobody', but the folder you're trying to write in belongs to a different user, the only way to have write rights to that folder would be if 'nobody' is in the same group, of if the folder has permissions 777 (write rights for everyone).

Comment: Yeah... but how can the user nobody be added to the user's group? Through cpanel?

Comment: That depends on your system. For Linux, it's mostly `usermod -G <groups> <user>`